# Notes Domino 8.5.3 Excel OLE XLXS issue

Tags: excel, lotus-domino, ole

I have a database where users can create new excel documents using ole objects. That makes it easier to copy content from complex excel files into a new spreadsheet without the need to edit or modify existing links and connections to other excel documents.
We are using Notes Domino 8.5.3 and MS Office 2010. 
Unfortunately the new Excel files are created within compability mode, so that complex spreadsheets cannot be copied into the new file, as the basefile hat too much cells for the old excel format.

Is threre a way how to control whether the new files become native Office 2010 XLXS Files instead of the old Office 2000 XLS files ?

Comment: Can you describe this process in a little more detail? E.g., do the users manually inset the Excel OLE object into an empty rich text field in the Notes document, or does the Notes form that they use contain an embedded OLE object that is copied into the new documents (as specified in the options in the form properties)?

Comment: Without a clue about "how" you create the excel- files (show code) it is not possible to tell you anything about the "why"

Comment: Are you saving the files as "*.xls" or "*.xlsx"?

Comment: Sorry. Havn´t been here for a while. The user creates a new Notes Document using a form called excelFile that launches a new MS Excel file at startup. I guess, the form is most part stolen from the document library. The user do not have to put in the object into a richtext field manually. OLE Object launch is configured at creation, modification and reading of the (Notes) document. I hope, this describes a little better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but I had a similar situation, where I was using templates stored as *.dotx files in a richtext field. I opened the original *.dotx files and used the 'Save As..' dialog to resave them under the format 'Word Template (.dotx). Word told me that it was saving the document with all the new goodies.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for you help. We solved the problem a similar way. We first save the new created document, too. And then we put it in as a normal launchable attachement. The comfort of the above discribed way (we still use for smaller spreadsheets) was, that they have been able to create the new file in a single step. Now they have to create, save and then embedd the file.